# How to get the data of the report (jrxml file) when running the Jasper Report server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have created an iReport based on the jrxml file and ran the report in Jasper Server. But after running the report I am getting the preview of the report without any data in it. I have set all the database what I am using in Jasper Server and in iReport.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Data Source is set correctly on the server. Check your iReport connection string and credentials first, then review report Data Source details on the server.